# Error Type not Allowed

Tags: c++, visual-c++

`The ERROR! starts from line 7` which is `GradeBook::GradeBook(string name)(Type name is not Allowed)`
I Wrote it the same as in the example cant understand why its not working and I am using visual studio 2015 to compile.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "Header.h" 
using namespace std; 
int main() { 
    GradeBook::GradeBook (string name) {
        setCourseName(name); 
    } 
    void GradeBook::setCourseName(string name) { 
        coursename = name; 
    } 
    string GradeBook::getCourseName() { 
        return courseName; 
    } 
    void GradeBook::displayMessage() { 
        cout << "Welcome to the Grade Book\n" << getCourseName <<"!" << endl; 
    } 
    system("PAUSE"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 GradeBook::GradeBook (string name)
 {
  setCourseName(name);
 }
 void GradeBook::setCourseName(string name)
 {
  coursename = name;
 }
 string GradeBook::getCourseName()
 {
  return courseName;
 }
 void GradeBook::displayMessage()
 {
  cout << "Welcome to the Grade Book\n" << getCourseName <<"!" << endl;
 }

 system("PAUSE");
 return 0;
}

Comment: Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49217428/edit) link to edit your post and add the code there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the definitions of the member functions of your class outside `main`.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "Header.h" 

using namespace std; 

GradeBook::GradeBook (string name) {
   setCourseName(name); 
} 

void GradeBook::setCourseName(string name) { 
   coursename = name; 
} 

string GradeBook::getCourseName() { 
   return courseName; 
} 

void GradeBook::displayMessage() { 
   cout << "Welcome to the Grade Book\n" << getCourseName <<"!" << endl; 
} 

int main() { 
   system("PAUSE"); 
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

We cannot define functions inside the another function in c++.

```
int main() { 
   GradeBook::GradeBook (string name) {
     setCourseName(name); 
   } 
   void GradeBook::setCourseName(string name) { 
     coursename = name; 
   } 
  return 0;  
}
```

but can declare function in another function.

and any other IDE also don't allow to define function in another function. You can define like this.

```
GradeBook::GradeBook (string name) {
   setCourseName(name); 
 } 
void GradeBook::setCourseName(string name) { 
 coursename = name; 
} 

 int main(){
     GradeBook b;
  return 0;   
 }
```